# Question of checking the $n$th root

Tags: algorithms

**Problem:**
Input : $n$, $k$

Check : Is $\frac{k}{4h -1} = n^{\frac{1}{h}}$? for any $  0 \le h <= n$.

**Question:** What is the fastest algorithm for the above problem assuming the model of computation is RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

$$f(h) = \left( {k \over 4h-1} \right)^h$$

is monotonically decreasing for $h < k+1/4$, and monotonically increasing for $h>k+1/4$.  (How do I know?  Set $f'(h)=0$ and solve for $h$.)

Therefore, one approach is to use a binary search on $h$ within the range $[0, \min(k+1/4,n)]$ to search for $h$ such that $f(h)=n$, followed by another binary search on $h$ within the range $[k+1/4, n]$.  You could also replace the binary search with a method with faster convergence, such as Newton's method.

Comment: I wish I could study CS and Maths from where you studied

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side is undefined if h=0, so 1 <= h <= n, and there is no solution if n=0. h=1 is a solution if and only if k=3n. So we can assume n >= 2, h>=2.

The h-th root of an integer n is an integer if n is an h-th power, and irrational otherwise. So we have 4h-1 dividing k, and n is exactly a a h-th power. We can check which powers of p divide n, for primes p = 2, 3, 5, 7, ..., 97 for example and if any primes divide n, h must be a divisor of the gcd of these numbers. This would vastly reduce the choices for h. If there are no divisors < 100 then n >= 101^h which also reduces the choices.